# Check if wxUniChar is a digit

Tags: c++, string, wxwidgets, digits

I have this condition:

```cpp
if (isdigit(exp.at(i)))
```

Where `exp` is: `wxString exp(MainText->GetValue());`

The `isdigit` function causes the program to crash because I'm working with Unicode characters like √. Is there a function that does the same job but works with wxString and therefore Unicode characters?

Comment: Did you google? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/isdigit-iswdigit-isdigit-l-iswdigit-l

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are wrappers for many CRT functions, and [wxIsdigit](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__crt.html#gaa354b14ed00785078e621932e2cf39b3) is probably what you need.